# Finish procedure before starting a new one

Tags: android, json

I am beginner in Android and I need some help. So, I have a procedure with sub-procedures inside. How can I finish one before starting a new one. Here is a code to better understand:

```
public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation lokacija) {
        super.onCellLocationChanged(lokacija);
        location = (GsmCellLocation) Phone.getCellLocation();
        textCellId.setText(String.valueOf(location.getCid() % 65536));
        textCellLac.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLac()));
        String JSON_URL_string=JSON_URL + "?cellid=" + String.valueOf(location.getCid()%65636);
        getJSON(JSON_URL_string);
        myJSONString = textCellNameSakriven.getText().toString();
        ParseJSON(myJSONString);
    }
```

Problem is that myJSONString is empty, cause textCEllNameSkriven is also empty. That textView textCellNameSkriven is made when getJSON(JSON_URL_string) is finished. If I run debugger and go step by step, app goes directly from getJSON(JSON_URL_string) row to the next one and the next etc

Edit: Maybe the problem is that onPostExecute is not finished before starting ParseJSON. Here is also a code for getJSON:

```
private void getJSON(String url) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait...", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String uri = params[0];

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");

                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                textCellNameSakriven.setText(s);
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(url);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running a async task it practically runs on a different thread, so your getJson method need not wait for post execute and can return after starting the async task, so you can never be sure in this way that parseJson gets executed after textView is populated. You are running into classic race condition issue.

Your issue could be easily solved, if you have a callback which is called after postExecute is done, and you can handle parseJson there

So, something simple like , create interface MyCallback

```
public interface MyCallback {
    public OnReadJsonDone();
}
```

Let your activity implement this MyCallback

```
public MainActivity implements MyCallback
{
  ...........
  @Override
   public OnReadJsonDone(){
      parseJson();
   }
```

Now change signature of getJson to

```
getJSON(string json, final MyCallback callback) {
```

Now in onpostexecute

```
//call OnReadJsonDone
callback.OnReadJsonDone()
```

So, all you now need is while calling getJSon pass this as second param

```
 getJSON(JSON_URL_string,this);
```

Haven't tested this but you get the idea

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Can you suggest me a solution with a code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have given a brief outline, rest you can take from there